# how to make custom bootstrap grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a custom bootstrap grid like this but the results aren't good:

This is the grid I want to make:

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 box-area">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 slide-area">  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the link isnt working

Comment: which link is not working?

Comment: [this is the grid I want to make.][1]

Comment: i fixed up the link thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid systems are responsive. Basically, these grids are constantly transforming on devices with different screen size. So you will have to deal with the other devices that has a smaller screen size if you're working on a larger screen like desktop.

I'm going to discuss the basics on how the grid system works but I am not making the code for what you are wanting to achive.

**Key breakpoints**

Are media queries pertaining to the device's screen size.

- <768px screen size — Extra small device (phones).
- 768px screen size — Small device (tablets).
- 992px screen size — Medium device (desktop)
- 1200px screen size — Large device (large desktop).

> Phones are the ones with less than 768px screen size, so it is
>   considered as an extra small device...

**Class Prefixes**

The class prefix that used for creating grids are all pointing to the key breakpoints.

- `col-xs` — Extra Small (XS - <768px)
- `col-sm` — Small (SM - 768px)
- `col-md` — Medium (MD - 992px)
- `col-lg` — Large (LG - 1200px)

There are overall 12 columns you can create with the grid system. That column itself can be divided depending on what screen size you prefer for them to appear divided with the class prefix.

> E.g — You want to display your contents divided into 3 columns on a
>   medium device screen. In that case you're going to use the class
>   prefix `col-md` and to have them separated into 3 on your web page,
>   you'll have to add 4 to the class prefix since you're dividing the
>   whole 12 columns into 3 parts. So then your class will be `col-md-4`.

You can read it all on the Bootstrap's [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) in great detail with some examples so you can fully understand its use.

Comment: thanks a lot for the guide . I know the bootstrapt system grid but i don't know how can i use it .would you give me an example? thanks

Comment: Here's a demo code (http://jsbin.com/gaxolofebi/edit?output) I've divided the column into 3 on extra small and medium devices so then I've combined the class prefixes col-xs and col-md. And there you'll see 3 rows separated by <hr> that each has 3 columns. Column lets say is horizontal and the row is vertical. So if you want 3 columns vertically, you'll have to separate each column with the row class. I recommend you to read the documentaion about grid system at the bootstrap's site.